# I want to create LiveCD bootable usb 1TB hard drive from existing system

Tags: hard-drive, iso, clone

I want to create a bootable copy of existing ubuntu system on external hard drive, do not need data, tried Pinguy Buiolder which creates iso but when I create new system with Etcher or Startup Disk Creator it asks for user / pass and no combination works.  Tried just manually installing system twice, once on laptop and once on external but now external coming up as read only, shows only limited software center options and when I boot again all changes are gone.  Please, I need help to create bootable copy of system without user data

Comment: Take a look at [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback)

Comment: Do you want to copy on the external hard drive *portable* to rather similar computers? - Or portable to almost all PC computers? Or do you intend to run it only in one computer? - Are you running in BIOS mode or UEFI mode? - Are you prepared to work in several steps, or do you need a quick fix?

Comment: Hi basically I want a duplicate of my laptop system on an external hard drive so if my laptop hard drive fails I can boot from external hard drive on same laptop.  I do not need to install on other computers.  So only one computer.  UEFI mode. Several steps is fine - thankyou.